# Extending varchar column size from 255 to 1024 characters doesn't appear to be using copy algorithm in Mysql 8.x DB with InnoDB storage

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, innodb

I have come across https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html MySql document which says extending length of a varchar column from 255 to 1024 is only possible with algorithm copy.
I am attaching a snippet from the doc here
[image]

However, when I tried to run alter sql on a table to achieve this, I received strange results. I have a table table1 with column col1 of varchar(255) on which I ran alter sql.

Execution of following sql took **0.07** seconds

```
Alter table table1 modify column col1 varchar(1024)
```

Whereas, execution of following sql took **26.54** seconds

```
Alter table table1 modify column col1 varchar(1024), algorithm=copy
```

As per the doc, this alter operation can only be performed using copy algorithm but query results show otherwise. The queries are run on MySql Db version 8.0.32 with InnoDB storage engine. Can someone help me to understand why I am observing mentioned behaviour?

Other observation was decreasing length of varchar from 1024 to 255 took 26.54 secs with/without copy algorithm which infers that decreasing it is indeed using copy algorithm then why the reverse operation doesn't do the same ?

Execution of alter Sql took 0.07 secs without specifying any algorithm but same took 26.54 secs with copy algorithm. I expected both to take 26.54 secs.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  What character set on the table and/or the column?

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.32 and charset of column is utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: `utf8` needs 3 bytes; 3*255 > 255, so already needed 2-byte len.

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR(255)` allows up to 255 *characters*.  If the column is, for example, declared `CHARACTER SET utf8mmb4`, then the number of *bytes* is up to 4*255, thereby necessitating 2 bytes of length to start with.

The documentation possibly needs updating; it was written more than a decade ago.  It may apply as is to `CHARACTER SET latin1`, the old default.  (`latin1` needs only 1 byte per character.)

Comment: Other observation was decreasing length of varchar from 1024 to 255 took 26.54 secs with/without copy algorithm which infers that decreasing it is indeed using copy algorithm then why the reverse operation doesn't do the same ?

Comment: Decreasing implied truncation.  Increasing implied allowing more chars (assuming it already had 2-byte length field).

Comment: Since utf8 takes 3bytes so we are assuming that 255 characters already took 2 bytes and storing 1024 characters also need 2 bytes as per doc hence there is no change in storage bytes when length is increased from 255 to 1024. Similarly, decreasing length from 1024 to 255 also will result is no change in storage bytes then why it is taking more time ?

Comment: Not storage bytes, but data being truncated.

Comment: There is no data exceeding length 255 currently(also, at the time of running above sqls) in the table.